# three.js gltf model becomes grey and textureless, after changing texture

Tags: three.js, gltf

hey guys i am new to three.js and i am trying to change my texture using Meshmatcap material. however, i am facing an issue where i change the texture, my model texture and color would disappear after adding `skinning: true` , which is necessary for my model to retain size . is there any way to solve this issue? thanks in advance.  currently using the model from https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/tyrannosaurus-rex-9d3a3e42c0054c35aa39c3ee07388d16

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>3d model</title>

  </head>


  <body>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.module.js';
        
        import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
        import { RGBELoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
        
        var container, controls;
        var camera, scene, renderer, mixer, clock;
        var obj , material , texture , mesh
        
        init();
        animate();
        
        function init() {
        
          container = document.getElementById( 'test' );
          document.body.appendChild( container );
          
          

          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000 );
          camera.position.x = 0
          camera.position.y = 2
          camera.position.z = 10 


        
          scene = new THREE.Scene();
        //   scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
          var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff,0x000000,10);
          scene.add(light);
            

          clock = new THREE.Clock(); 
              
              var loader = new GLTFLoader();

               // Load a glTF resource

    
              loader.load('scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
                
              var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

              mesh = gltf.scene.children[0]

              console.log(mesh)

              var texture = textureLoader.load('blue1.jpg');

              // texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

              

              var matcapMaterial = new THREE.MeshMatcapMaterial({ skinning: true ,normalMap: texture })

                obj = scene.add( mesh );

                obj.traverse((o) => {
                if (o.isMesh) o.material = matcapMaterial
                
                ;

                
                })
               
                ;

        
                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
                
                gltf.animations.forEach( ( clip ) => {
                  
                    mixer.clipAction( clip ).play();
                  
                } );
        
              } );



        
        
          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
          renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
          renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
          renderer.toneMappingExposure = 0.8;
          renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
          container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        
       
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
          camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        
        //
        
        function animate() {
          requestAnimationFrame( animate );
          var delta = clock.getDelta();
          if ( mixer ) mixer.update( delta );
          renderer.render( scene, camera );
        
        }

        </script>

<div id="test">

</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When replacing textures of glTF asset with manually loaded textures, you have to set the `Texture.flipY` property to `false` in order to accommodate the uv convention of glTF.

This circumstance is also mentioned in the [documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=gltf#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) of `THREE.GLTFLoader`.

Comment: its working now thanks mate